# Can the Debye functions be implemented using built-in functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, built-in-symbols

It is claimed in the comments [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107507/how-to-use-solve-command/107513#107513) that the [Debye functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DebyeFunctions.html) can be implemented using built-in special functions. This is clearly true for *some* Debye functions, e.g., $D_n^{(1)}(x)$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$ (see linked article, which gives these explicitly). However, I'm not sure whether the comment holds in general.

For example, I'm interested in the following integral:

$$D_{-1}^{(2)}(x) = \int_x^\infty \frac{dt}t \frac1{e^t - 1}.$$

Can this integral be represented exactly, in closed form, using built-in special functions? More generally, can the functions $D_n^{(1)}$ and $D_n^{(2)}$ be represented exactly for all integer $n$?

**Edit:** By "represented exactly, in closed form, using built-in special functions" I mean using built-in functions that are quickly evaluated numerically, without relying on `NIntegrate` or `NSolve` or other explicit numerical functions.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean and what your end-goal is. For example, $D_{-1}^{(2)}(x)$ is respresented in Mathematica _exactly_ with `Integrate[1/(t (Exp[t] - 1)), {t, x, ∞}]`. Perhaps you may want to elaborate what you want to do with these functions.

Comment: I mean represented exactly using built-in special functions that Mathematica can numerically evaluate "quickly" and to arbitrary precision. Compare, e.g., `Timing@Integrate[x^2 E^-x, {x, 1., Infinity}]` to `Timing@Gamma[3, 1.]`. In this example, `Gamma` is the "built-in special function" that computes the given integral.

Comment: Well, then perhaps you should make it more clear in your question that you are not really looking for an "exact" symbolic representation but for an efficient numerical evaluation.

Comment: @Domen I edited the post.

Answer (score 4):

This only partially answers your question so I'll delete if it is not what you're looking for.

The first type of functions, $D^{(1)}_n (x)$ satisfy the differential equation
$$D^{'(1)}_n (x) = \frac{x^n}{e^x-1} \\ \mathrm{with} \\ D^{(1)}_n (0) = 0$$

(I got the initial condition from looking at the integral definition on the [MathWorld site](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DebyeFunctions.html) at x = 0)

**Edit:** I missed on the MathWorld site it also mentions that  $D^{(1)}_n (x)$ is only valid for $|x| < 2 \pi$, so just keep that in mind.

```
diff[n_] = D[d[x], x] == x^n/(E^x - 1);
soln1 = Table[ DSolveValue[{diff[n], d[0] == 0}, d[x], x], {n, 5}];
Plot[soln1, {x, -6, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Subsuperscript[D, n, 1], {n, 5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So we can write:

```
debyeD1[n_, x_] := DSolveValue[{diff[n], d[0] == 0}, d[x], x]
```

or alternatively using the integral definition:

```
debyeD1[n_, 
  x_] := (Integrate[x^n/(Exp[x] - 1), x] + (n! + Zeta[n + 1]))
```

The second type of functions, $D^{(2)}_n (x)$ satisfy the differential equation
$$D^{'(2)}_n (x) = -\frac{x^n}{e^x-1} \\
 \mathrm{with} \\
 D^{(2)}_n (0) = n! \zeta (n+1)$$

This initial condition is also from the MathWorld site, as it says:
$$D^{(1)}_n (x) + D^{(2)}_n (x) = n! \zeta (n+1)$$ And we know $D^{(1)}_n (0)$ is 0

```
diff2[n_] = D[d[x], x] == -(x^n/(E^x - 1));
soln2 = Table[ 
   DSolveValue[{diff2[n], d[0] == n! Zeta[n + 1]}, d[x], x], {n, 5}];
Plot[soln2, {x, -6, 6}, 
 PlotLegends -> Table[Subsuperscript[D, n, 2], {n, 5}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And confirming that the condition
$$D^{(1)}_n (x) + D^{(2)}_n (x) = n! \zeta (n+1)$$
is met:

```
sums = soln1 + soln2;
sums/Table[n! Zeta[n + 1], {n, 5}] // Simplify
(*{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}*)
```

So we can write:

```
debyeD2[n_, x_] := 
 DSolveValue[{diff2[n], d[0] == n! Zeta[n + 1]}, d[x], x]
```

or alternatively using the integral definition:

```
debyeD2[n_, x_] := -Integrate[x^n/(Exp[x] - 1), x]
```

**The only problem is I don't know how to do $D^{(2)}_{-1} (x)$**

```
neg1 = {diff2[n], d[0] == n! Zeta[n + 1]}/.n->-1
(*{Derivative[1][d][x] == -(1/((-1 + E^x) x)), d[0] == ComplexInfinity}*)
```

because `n!` is not defined I believe at negative integers.
Maybe someone else can fill in on this part. The integral definition doesn't evaluate either so I can't figure out how to show an exact form for $D^{(2)}_{-1} (x)$.

Comment: This is very nice, but my intention was to avoid calling on numerical computation functions. E.g., in the way that `Gamma[3, 1]` represents (and quickly computes) `Integrate[x^2 E^(-x), {x, 1, Infinity]`.

Comment: These are not numerical computation functions, they are all exact solutions. But I think you are saying you want to find a general solution for `Integrate[x^n/(-1 + E^x), x, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]` ? This seems challenging, but perhaps it is possible.

Comment: Yes, but if Mathematica had a built-in function `Debye[n, z]` that calculated this automatically, I would consider that a solution. I guess one could argue that there's nothing special about such built-in functions because they still need to execute algorithms to compute values, but they do tend to be very fast and easy to use.

Comment: @WillG Ah I see

Comment: There is a publication over approximations of the Debye function at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348068830_Analytic_approximation_of_the_Debye_function